# wordpress select query not working

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I am struggling with a select query for wordpress, which is not working. The weird part is that I have 2 select queries, 1 at a current running website and works. And an almost similar select query on a local test machine and is not working.

Here is the query from the live, which is working:

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.* 
    FROM wp_users as users 
    INNER JOIN wp_usermeta as mt 
        ON (users.ID = mt.user_id) 
    WHERE 1=1 
        AND (mt.meta_value LIKE '%Trainer%') 
        AND (mt.meta_key = '_upme_search_cache' AND mt.meta_value LIKE '%ACTIVE%') 
        AND (   (mt.meta_key = '_upme_search_cache' AND mt.meta_value NOT LIKE '%administrator%') 
            AND (mt.meta_key = '_upme_search_cache' AND mt.meta_value NOT LIKE '%sportentrainer%') ) 
    ORDER BY users.user_registered asc LIMIT 9
```

And here the query from the local machine:

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.* 
    FROM wp_users as users 
    INNER JOIN wp_usermeta as mt 
        ON (users.ID = mt.user_id) 
    WHERE 1=1 
        AND (mt.meta_value LIKE '%trainer%') 
        AND (mt.meta_key = 'sent_activation_status' AND mt.meta_value LIKE '%ACTIVE%') 
        AND (  (mt.meta_key = 'account_type' AND mt.meta_value NOT LIKE '%administrator%') 
            OR (mt.meta_key = 'account_type' AND mt.meta_value NOT LIKE '%sportentrainer%') ) 
    ORDER BY users.user_registered asc LIMIT 9
```

The meta_key on the second query are all found when searching for them separately. You notice that the meta_keys are different, but that is not the problem.

The first query runs on a live version of phpmyadmin: 4.1.9 and mysql: 5.0.12 (if I am correct) and the second query runs on the local version of phpmyadmin: 4.6.6 and mysql: 5.6.35

Can someone see why the second query is not working?

Comment: By _not working_ do you mean that the query doesn't return the results that you'd like it to? If so, then probably the best thing to do would be to debug by simplifying the query. Start with just one `AND` / `OR` condition, run the query, check if you get the data till that point, add more conditions, verify the results again and keep going until you find a disconnect. Maybe there actually is nothing in the table that matches your expectations? Or if there is, then perhaps the conditions aren't formulated accurately? MySQL versions shouldn't really make any difference to this query.

Comment: By not working, I mean it returns 0 results. When I use only 1 AND it returns  results. So the weird part is, that the first query returns results, but just modifying the meta_keys returns 0 results, but when I search in phpmyadmin for those meta_keys and a specific value, it returns results as well. So the meta_keys are there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will not return any result because of the following conditions:

```
AND (mt.meta_key = 'sent_activation_status' AND mt.meta_value LIKE '%ACTIVE%') 
AND ((mt.meta_key = 'account_type' AND mt.meta_value NOT LIKE '%administrator%') 
            OR (mt.meta_key = 'account_type' AND mt.meta_value NOT LIKE '%sportentrainer%'))
```

If you look at the above condition, it says `mt.meta_key = 'sent_activation_status' AND mt.meta_key = 'account_type'`, now, this won't be possible as `meta_key` can't be `sent_activation_status` and `account_type` at the same time.

If you want to get the results, you need to use `OR` rather than `AND`.

Comment: HI Darshan, thanks for reply, still the same result, returns 0.

Comment: I tried the following SQL: `SELECT DISTINCT users.* FROM wp_users as users INNER JOIN wp_usermeta as mt ON (users.ID = mt.user_id) WHERE 1=1 AND (mt.meta_value LIKE '%trainer%') AND (mt.meta_key = 'sent_activation_status' AND mt.meta_value LIKE '%ACTIVE%')` Which doesn't work, but when running only: `SELECT DISTINCT users.* FROM wp_users as users INNER JOIN wp_usermeta as mt ON (users.ID = mt.user_id) WHERE 1=1 AND (mt.meta_value LIKE '%trainer%')` it works. I am confused.

Comment: thanks, you are correct. I will have to change the way the values are stored. Thanks again.